# How to prevent client to view WebResource.axd until user login?

Tags: c#, webforms

My Web application has WebResource.axd handler. but it is visible either user has session or not.

Is it possible to prevent client to browse WebResource.axd before logging in?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding this code in Global.asax

```
  protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        HttpRequest request = this.Request;
        HttpResponse response = this.Response;
        if (request.RawUrl.IndexOf(".axd") > -1)
        {
            if (!IsLogined())
            {
                response.Redirect("/notauth.js");
                

            }
        }
    }
```